# Posting an array of objects not working with Restkit

Tags: ios, restkit

I have the following two entities

```
@interface MEContactInfo : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* phone ;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* email;
@end

@interface MEContact : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* _id ;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* lastName;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* firstName;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* data ;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray* contactInfos ;
@end
```

The second entity contact contains the array of contact infos. Now I want to post this to my server but I am not able to do so. My mappings are as following:

```
RKObjectMapping* contactMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MEContact class]];
[contactMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"_id",@"lastName",@"firstName",@"data"]];

RKObjectMapping* contactInfosMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MEContactInfo class]];
[contactInfosMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"email",@"phone"]];
[contactMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"contactInfos" toKeyPath:@"contactInfos" withMapping:contactInfosMapping]];
```

My request descriptor is as following:

```
requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor 
requestDescriptorWithMapping:[contactMapping inverseMapping]    
objectClass: [MEContact class]  
rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodAny];
```

Now when I post something like this:

> { firstName:”abc”,
>         lastName:”xyz”,
>       contactInfos: [{
>           email:”test@test.com”,
>           phone:”9999999999”
>       }]
>   }

I receive

> {
>       firstName:”abc”,
>       lastName:”xyz”,
>       contactInfos: [ ”test@test.com”,”9999999999”]
>   }

If I have multiple entries in the contactInfos array, they all are appended to the contactInfos array I receive on the server side. Basically the contactInfo object is flattening in an array. Can you please let me know how I can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Everything above was correct. The problem was that data was not going as JSON to the server. The solution was that I had to set request serialization MimeType which can be done by doing this

[objectManger setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];

Thanks